# CMake : execute target Debug or Release at install time

Tags: installation, cmake, target, execute

In my CMake project I generate a target "MyProgram" with

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(MyProgram ...)
```

Then, at install time, I would like to execute this program (with some arguments) so I use

```
INSTALL(SCRIPT MyScript.cmake)
```

But with Windows + MSVC, I can't find a way to call the right executable :

- In Debug mode I want to call `${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/Debug/MyProgram.exe`
- In Release mode I want to call `${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/Release/MyProgram.exe`

I know a little about cmake-generator-expressions, but I couldn't make it work with `install(SCRIPT)`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either generate different script files knowing about the respective locations of the executables and use e.g. `install(SCRIPT "MyScript$<CONFIG>.cmake")` to use `MyScriptDebug.cmake` or `MyScriptRelease.cmake` for Debug or Release configurations respectively or alternatively use `install(CODE)` allowing you to pass parameters to the script:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND \"${CMAKE_COMMAND}\" -D \"MY_PROGRAM=$<TARGET_FILE:MyProgram>\" -P MyScript.cmake)")
```

**MyScript.cmake**

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${MY_PROGRAM} ...)
...
```

For calling a single program you may not need a script file though; you may simply be able to call the program directly using

```
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND \"$<TARGET_FILE:MyProgram>\" ...)")
```